# How do i nest an array inside my dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

Got a little issue here, first time working with `Array` inside Dictionaries. This is not working:
`var level2Dictionary = [String : [array]]()` 
i get error:

> Reference to generic type Array requires arguments in <...>.

How should i call this?! All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change your declaration like this

```
level2Dictionary = [String : [AnyObject]]()
```

**Note:** You can change `AnyObject` with the type you want with your `Array` like `String`, `Int`, or might `Dictionary` what ever that you want.